# sending mail for frequently changing users

Tags: shell-script

I want to use a control file where I have all my mail Ids stored in a directory say Ex: /abs/pqr/send_mail.ctrl

Sample of control send_mail.ctrl

```
abc@domain.com
str@domain.in
------
-----
```

Now I want to export that list which I declared in ctrl file in my main script where I am using mailx command to send the mail.

How should I handle this situation without changing the main script to sent mail to list of dynamic users which is changing on daily basis ?

Comment: To whom do you want to export that list?  Other programs running on the same host?  Or other hosts in the same LAN?  Or remote hosts in foreign networks?

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
cat /abs/pqr/send_mail.ctrl | while read a b; do
 /some/where/main_script.sh $a
done
```

it calls the main script for each entry in the control file with the first (blank-separation) column found in the control file as parameter..